# Can I set object viewport colour from cycles nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I have a setup like this in a cycles material:

[image]

Is there a way to set the viewport colour using this ramp node?

So far, I just have a solid viewport color:

[image]

The material view still doesn't reflect the render:

[image]

Here's how they're coloured in the render:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that. In Cycles, you can only use only one solid viewport color. This node setup would not show up, in the 3d solid view, but it can show in material view

Comment: A solid viewport colour is fine, I was just hoping I could set said colour from a node. Material view is fine though, thanks!

Comment: @Always4u Material view doesn't actually work either.. I'll update my question.

Comment: For complex materials, try to bake the material into textures, and then view it using material view

Comment: I bet you could script this somehow via python...

Comment: @Samoth I'm actually not so sure.. You may be right, but I want to use the same material across all the object.

Comment: @Always4u That might be a solution. Can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you cannot set more than a single color per Material on an object in cycles, it is possible to get multiple colors as you showed in the LookDev (2.8) view mode.

the reason you do not see the random color array is because in cycles the random, just like the pointiness is only claculated in the render.

Comment: One sentence rarely makes a good answer. By the length of your answer alone, it should be a comment. You can put a little more effort into it, for example by explaining the technical reasons behind this behavior. This would rise your reputation, which makes [commenting on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) available.